# Hello World for Rules and Actions in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I am learning sitecore Rule and readthe material on [Rule Engine Cook Book](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/61/rules_engine_cookbook_sc61_a4.pdf). I just want to show a message window on Item save. This is what I did so far:

1. Added a `Rule` under  `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Item Saved/Rules`.

Rule 1:
where the item template is `Address entry`
run `Show Hello World` script

2. Added a script `Show Hello World` under `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Item Saved/Actions/`

in the script there are 3 fields which I need to fill as the cookbook says, `Enter a value in the Type field, or a value in the Code, References, and Language fields. Do not enter values in all four fields.` Therefore I filled the fields with following data:

**code:** `Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Alert("More than one address not allowed under this item!");`

**References**: I don't know what to write here.

**Language**: `CSharp`

I don't know what I am doing wrong here. Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just successfully recreated your script and tested it on a fresh Sitecore instance. Here are the steps you must follow:

1. Add a new item of the template type `/sitecore/templates/System/Rules/Script` under `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements/Script`. I called my item "mydemoscript". If you are running an earlier version of Sitecore (I think 7.2 or earlier) then your save path will be `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Item Saved/Actions`
2. In the script's `Code` field add the following:<%Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Alert("More than one address not  allowed under this item!");%>
3. In the script's `Type` field add "CSharp"
4. Save your script item.
5. Under `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Item Saved/Rules` create a rule, I named mine "mydemo"
6. In the `Rule` field use the same condition as you did before. For the action use "run specific script" action. Be sure to edit the action to refer to the script that you created in steps 1-4.
7. Test!

Comment: Thanks for answer! There is no Folder named "Definitions". under /sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/

Comment: What version of Sitecore are you running?

Comment: I am using Sitecore 7.0

Comment: Hi Kami, sorry I haven't got back to you sooner! The only difference to the instructions above for your version of Sitecore is in step 1. I've edited my steps to reflect the change.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I've ever seen `code` field being used in `Actions` item.

The easiest way of executing some code on action is using the `Type` field with value:

> My.Assembly.Namespace.MyCustomAction,My.Assembly

And then `MyCustomAction` class code:

```cs
using Sitecore.Data;
using Sitecore.Rules.Actions;

namespace My.Assembly.Namespace
{
  public class MyCustomAction<T> : RuleAction<T> where T : ConditionalRenderingsRuleContext
  {
    public override void Apply(T ruleContext)
    {
        // your code here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So basically for this kind of functionality, Working with Events Handlers is more appropriate ??

Comment: Actions are absolutely fine. Just don't use `Code, References, and Language fields`, use `Type` field instead.

Comment: I am still working on the solution you provided but still I am unable to see the message. I did exactly what you mentioned in your answer. but still I can't see any message. I tried to do some other stuff e.g. Editing an item field but still no success. Can you review your answer once more !!

Comment: Try to log some information and see if your code is executed at all `Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log(...)`

Comment: Yes the code is not executing all. I tried with logging but I can't see any entry in the logs.

Comment: Try to create a rule under `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Item Saved/Rules/` with condition `where true (actions always execute)` and select `run specific script` action (with your action selected) as the action of this rule. See `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Item Saved/Rules/Clear Rules Cache` rule for reference.